# Marker Label Position

Tags: label, markers

Marker labels can be hard to read, depending on the position of surrounding markers  (see example below).

Is there a way to position the label text below the marker icon rather than across the center of the icon?

[image: Marker Labels Example]

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Have you found any answer?

Comment: No, I moved on to other aspects of my app. There have not been any replies to this and my app can toggle alternate map service providers, so where it's an issue I toggle to another provider.

Comment: fyi, i posted [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56393756/how-to-position-the-label-inside-the-marker-in-google-map/56396650?noredirect=1#comment99402113_56396650). hope it helps