# How to position the label inside the Marker in Google Map?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

[image]

As shown in the picture, my label '150' is strictly located at the center. But i would like to move up a little bit. Is this possible?
Note that I am using markers clustering. So i have to use 'Markers' type (correct me if I am wrong)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [the documentation for the `Icon`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/marker#Icon) anonymous object:

> **labelOrigin**
>   Type:  Point
>   The origin of the label relative to the top-left corner of the icon image, if a label is supplied by the marker. By default, the origin is located in the center point of the image.

To move the label, set the labelOrigin property of the `Icon` to the required value.

Answer (score 1):

You can practically add the code as shown below:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(43.467946, -79.687896),
    icon: {
        url: 'active_map_marker.svg',
        labelOrigin: {
            x: 50,
            y: 90
        }
    },
    title: 'Oakville',
    label: {
        text: "Oakville",
        color: "#BF9778",
        fontSize: "16px",
        fontWeight: "400",
        top: "15px"
    },
});
marker.setMap(map);
```

**"labelOrigin"** property in icon will allow you to set the position of the label by taking the x and y coordinates as its value.